# vim how to search for URL

Tags: vim

How would you search for the following string in vim?

```
http://my.url.com/a/b/c
```

I've tried (a la Very No Magic)

```
:/\Vhttp://my.url.com/a/b/c
```

But it gives me:

`E492 not an editor command: /\Vhttp://my.url.com/a/b/c`

You would think there'd be a simple way to search a string literally... I'm not too interested in slash escaping every slash, or writing a complicated search, because I have to rapidly search different URLs in a text file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get `not an editor command` since I don't.  The simplest way to search without having to escape slashes is to use `?` instead, e.g.

```
:?http://my.url.com/a/b/c
" or since the : is not necessary
?http://my.url.com/a/b/c
```

This does search in the other direction, so just keep that in mind

Comment: The reason he got "not an editor command" is that he entered the search while in command mode -- indicated by the ":".

Comment: @MarkkuK. I don't get that when I run his exact command from his question though; it just tries to search for `\Vhttp:` for me; maybe a version difference

Comment: I think it's a version difference. I get 'not an editor command' on my remote machine (vim version 7.0) but not on local (vim version 7.3)

Comment: @ExplosionPills I get "E488: Trailing characters" in Vim 7.0.237 ... you are probably right about it being a version difference.

Comment: The backward search also reverses/swaps the "n" and "N" commands. I was told of a trick to get the search the right way round: perform and empty forward-seach by hitting "/" then <enter>, which will repeat the search but switch you back into the forward direction.

Comment: See my comment below about "Trailing characters"

Answer (score 4):

another way to search forward (from the position of your cursor)  without escaping is use `:s` command.

you could do:

```
:%s@http://my.url.com/a/b/c@@n
```

then press `n` to navigate matched text forward, `N` backwards

If you want to know how many matches in the buffer, use `gn` instead of `n`

note that, I said "without escaping", I was talking about the slash, if you want to do search precisely, you have to escape the period. `.`. since in regex, `.` means any char.

Comment: In neovim on mac OSX I have to use this with only a single `@` instead of `@@`

Answer (score 0):

Can also set the search register directly.

```
:let @/='\Vhttp://my.url.com/a/b/c'
```

Then you can use `n` and `N` like normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use MacVim (or GVim). Open the non-regex GUI search using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> on Windows). This is the recommended way to do a non-regex search in Vim. GUI Vim has many improvements over terminal vim like this one and I would highly suggest using it full time if you aren't already.

Answer (score -1):

Searching in vim is just `/`, not `:/`. You can search for that string escaping only the slashes: `/http:\/\/my.url.com\/a\/b\/c`

Comment: Downside: adding all those slashes is a pain if you are often doing searches for URLs; it's what I came here to avoid.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of the entire question