# How to use an alternate character other than '/' in a vim search (NOT search and replace)?

Tags: vim

I want to do a search and find something that I'm pasting in with a lot of `/` characters.  I would rather not have to escape every one of them as it is a PITA.

Is there some way of doing this?  In perl I'd just use `m#blah#`, but the `m` prefix doesn't seem to work in vim.

NOTE: I'm not wanting to escape the entire search string, just not use the `/` as a match delimiter.

Comment: See also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_without_need_to_escape_slash

Comment: Here's another one [with a more straightforward answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554010/vim-how-to-search-for-url)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, your 2nd and 3rd comments are the answers I was looking for.  Post it and I'll give you credit.

Comment: This will get linked as a duplicate to that one. It's not appropriate for me to lift the answer - you should upvote all of them over there instead

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, oh yeah, true.  How to mark as duplicate of 3rd comment?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ok, I voted to close based on your 3rd comment.  That or I can delete this question.

Comment: With no upvoted answers, I think you can delete it, but the dupe link is actually helpful for others searching